# Confusion over populating DropDownListFor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm just starting out in ASP.NET MVC and I've been having difficultly with the @Html.DropDownListFor property, I can't get my head around it! Hopefully some kind people could give me a hand?

I'm trying to re-build this page (http://goo.gl/q7H9Na) in ASP.NET MVC 4. If anyone could help me, it would be great if you could provide an example on how to get the "Party Size" field working. I've included what I've managed to do so far. Thanks for any help!

**View Model:**

```
namespace ThePines.ViewModels
{
    public class EnquiryForm
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter a first name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter a last name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter an email address")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter a valid email address")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter a country")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter a question")]
        public string Question { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Enquiries", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <table cellpadding="8" cellspacing="8">
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, "First Name")</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)</td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, "Last Name")</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)</td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "Email Address")</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress)</td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, "Country")</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Country)</td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PartySize, "Party Size")</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor()</td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartySize)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question, "Question")</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Question)</td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question)</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="Send Enquiry" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class EnquiriesController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Enquiries/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

    }

    // POST: /Enquiries/

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(EnquiryForm enquiryForm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }

        return View(enquiryForm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to add a PartySize property to your ViewModel:

```
public int PartySize { get; set; }
```

Then, in your Controller, you'll have:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new EnquiryForm();

    ViewBag.PartySizes = Enumearable.Range(1, 8);
    return View(model);
}
```

And, in your View, you'll have:

```
<tr>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PartySize, "Party Size")</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PartySize, new SelectList(ViewBag.PartySizes))</td>
    <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartySize)</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this through a `ViewBag`, but I keep the `SelectList` instantiation code where it should be, in the controller. Here's an example; I hope this helps:

**In View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PartySize, ViewBag.Sizes as SelectList, "Party Size")
```

**In ViewModel (add)**

```
public int PartySize { get; set; }
```

**In Controller**

```
List<int> Sizes = new List<int>();

        for(int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
        {
            Sizes.Add(i);
        }

        ViewBag.Sizes = new SelectList(Sizes);
```

Answer (score -1):

Create one class called

```
public class KeyValuePair 
{
  public string Text;
  public string Text;
}
```

In Get Index Action

```
List<KeyValuePair> keyValuePair = new List<KeyValuePair>(); //Add your drop down values into this list
ViewBag.PartySize= new SelectList(keyValuePair, "Value", "Text", selectedValue: id);
```

On View page

```
<td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PartySize, "Party Size")</td>
<td>@Html.DropDownList("PartySize",(SelectList)ViewBag.PartySize)</td>
<td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartySize)</td>
```

Comment: There's no need to create a `KeyValuePair` class.